# Submit button not respond for action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an odd problem !! my submit button not respond for action !!!

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save_contact_information() {

        document.getElementById('User_Finder').action = "Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";

    }
</script>
<form id="User_Finder" action="User_Finder.php?ID_CV_User=<?php print $ID_CV_User ?>&&change_profile=ok"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="submit" id="CI_BT_Save" onclick="save_contact_information()"
    name="BT_PI_Save" value="Save" style="position:absolute;left:12px;top:333px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:342;">

</form>
```

if I click on the button save , nothing will be change !!!
I change the code of the function 'save_contact_information()'  as bellow:

```
function save_contact_information() {
    alert("ok1");
    document.getElementById('User_Finder').action = "Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";
    alert("ok2");
}
```

Now if I Click on button save , 2 alerts will be visible : ok1 + ok2 but this line :
`document.getElementById('User_Finder').action ="Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";` not given any reaction !!!

Have anyone any idea about this ODD problem !!!

Comment: That is not an ODD problem. It is exactly what you asked the compiler to do. ;)

Comment: yup...exactly haha :) (y) (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function save_contact_information() {
alert("ok1");
                document.getElementById('User_Finder').action ="Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";
alert("ok2");
  document.getElementById('User_Finder').submit(); //here form submit with your action


            }
```

Comment: Thank u @Rituraj ratan :) ... it helped a lot !!! now it work (y) !!! big thanx for you sir :)

Comment: I will set your answer as true about 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

its a form so u have to add `event.preventDefault()`

**EDIT:**
Do this

```
function save_contact_information() {
    alert("ok1");
event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('User_Finder').action = "Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";
    alert("ok2");
document.getElementById('User_Finder').submit();
}
```

Comment: but in an anothor submit button I do the same thing (document.getElementById('User_Finder').action =......) and it work very good !!!

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("User_Finder").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
function save_contact_information() {
var myForm = document.getElementById('User_Finder');
myForm.action ="Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";
myForm.submit();
}
```

**Details:**

Since your button is calling another function, the call to new action will only happen on the next click. You may also trigger the submit of the form again by manually calling the submit function.

> You may also want to declare `myForm` variable one off to **avoid heavy
>   DOM manipulations** every-time you try to search for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of on click for submit button use on submit in form tag with return. That is better approach. It will work.

```
<form id="User_Finder" action="User_Finder.php?ID_CV_User=<?php print $ID_CV_User ?>&&change_profile=ok" method="post" onsubmit="return save_contact_information()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="submit" id="CI_BT_Save" name="BT_PI_Save" value="Save" style="position:absolute;left:12px;top:333px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:342;">

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function save_contact_information() {

    document.getElementById('User_Finder').action = "Controler/controller_page.php?button=save_contact_information";
    return true;

}
</script>
```

Try to avoid onclick event for submit button always